# How do I find out who provides my water?

Tags: home

I live in a rented house in a rural part of California.  The water is piped in from somewhere else in the area, and paid for by the landlord.  (And apparently it's contaminated.)

How do I find out who my water provider is?

The property manager isn't sure (or isn't telling), the county health department tells me to talk to the state, and the state health department tells me to talk to the county.

Comment: Ask your landlord

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ask nicely in writing.

Get and use names whenever you can. Ask elected representatives in your jurisdiction.

Involve others

Squeeze whomever you ask by "cc"ing the local news agencies (print, radio, and television) if they brush you off. Let the person know that others are interested in this potential environmental/political/health issue. Involving the news media will force the issue. It is the equivalent of pouring gasoline on a fire.

Regional water resources are tested and the results are usually part of the public record stored at the town hall department for building permits, premises, registry of deeds, or nearby. A real estate broker or salesperson can usually find answers to such a question.

Local water can become contaminated between the public source and the user. If you suspect a problem, a good first step would be to verify your specific situation and then work from there. Maybe the landlord will split the cost of analysis with you. It's a deductible expense for the landowner in a rural area. Perhaps, a test has already been made because periodic testing is required by law.

A private nearby water-testing service would make it their business to know if their results are common to a specific aquifer.

Social Media

Some might include social media to get an idea of what others have experienced.